# My linux won't let me get in as user or even as a guest in login screen

Tags: 14.04, login-screen

I opened my computer and it was good and all , but then when my desktop was supposed to appear , there was some kind of log in window that has 2 options, to log in as my user name or as a guest.

The problem is that when I used my password it showed me that it's getting in but then a little window that says "system program problem detected.." for 2 seconds and it didn't even let me choose if to cancel or to report the problem.

I tried many times and then gave up and thought that I can use the guest mode for a while , but this one won't open too!

Comment: Are you using Unity ubuntu-desktop by default?

Comment: Open the virtual terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F2 ( to return to graphics use Ctrl +Alt +F7). Login, and run `ls -l ~/.Xauthority` Notice, there's no spaces between ~,/ and there's a leading dot in .Xauthority. Let us know if `-rw------- 1 root root 53 Jun 23 18:47 .Xauthority` . If you see your username there, not root, then that's not the problem. Also, try using different login manager as well. For example `sudo apt-get install gdm` and when you're prompted to, choose gdm as default.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was using the Ubuntu based operating system, Zorin OS and I didn't find a solution except booting into Gnome Recovery mode which Ubuntu doesn't have. I thought the problem was a bug to do with Zorin OS, so I ended up uninstalling Zorin and installing Ubuntu because I thought it would be more stable (and it is). **So the only solution I can think of is to uninstall Ubuntu and then install it again.**

Comment: Are you sure Ubuntu doesn't have recovery mode?

Comment: Actually sorry, I just found this tutorial on how to get into recovery mode in Ubuntu 14.04 on the ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Answer (score 0):

You could try just reading the crash logs. That's what causes that pop up. Run `sudo rm /var/crash/*` in a terminal. That should fix the problem after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem with window manager**

At your login screen, next to the user, there might be a ubuntu sign. When you click on there, there might be different window managers to choose from (ubuntu default/gnome/kde/...)

If not... try to get to the a terminal:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (*after you logged in on your desktop*)

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (*to login to tty console*) (*to go back to GUI <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>*)

(i dont know if you can find more info in /var/crash ... might be)

Install another window manager (i like this one):

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Then restart, and as explained at start, in your login screen, you should be able to change the windows manager next to your user.

Probably before, your desktop started up without login to your standard user. You can set this again in your system preferences whenever your windows manager is fixed again.